# How to change name of program on the preview in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

To clarify that I mean, I have added pic. And changing name of project doesn`t effect at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to change this `Title="Something.."` in the `MainWindow.xaml` code of main page

Comment: Oh, MainWindow title was different.

Answer (score 3):

Project Settings -> Application -> Assembly name -> Change this to your desired application name.

Comment: I said, I did this, there is smth different

Comment: You said you changed project name. Changing project name and changing assembly name is different.

Comment: What is your application name? and what is your project name?